# Replace text between pattern range on same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

This may be a better task for `awk` than `sed`, but the goal is to parse a single, long string (it happens to be an XML doc) and replace text within a pattern range with another character.

I want to preserve the number of characters being replaced and simply mask them as asterisks. I've put something together in a python script to parse the XML tree but have a feeling a native program is going to be much faster.

Assuming the string: `"<mask>123</mask><keep>123</keep>"`

...I'd like the output: `"<mask>***</mask><keep>123</keep>"`

My first attempt with `sed` without using ranges got me this:

```
$ echo "<mask>123</mask><keep>123</keep>" | sed "s/[0-9]/*/g"
<mask>***</mask><keep>***</keep>
```

I learned that `sed` can operate within ranges, but my understanding is that the behavior can only be toggled from line-to-line, not over the course of processing a single line.

Experimenting with pattern ranges got me the following (consistent with my understanding) and thus didn't work either:

```
$ echo "<mask>123</mask><keep>123</keep>" | sed "/<mask>/,/<\/mask>/ s/[0-9]/*/g" 
<mask>***</mask><keep>***</keep>
```

EDIT: In fact, even if there were line breaks in the input, I must not be understanding the pattern range behavior correctly (or my example is poorly constructed)

```
$ echo "<mask>123</mask>\n<keep>123</keep>" | sed "/<mask>/,/<\/mask>/ s/[0-9]/*/g" 
<mask>***</mask>
<keep>***</keep>
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `sed` is as much a native program as `python` is. Why do you think one of them is going to be faster?

Comment: `echo "<mask>123</mask>\n<keep>123</keep>"` does not actually produce a string with a line break in Bash. `echo $'<mask>123</mask>\n<keep>123</keep>'` does tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never use range expressions as they make simple tasks very slightly briefer but then need a complete rewrite or duplicate conditions when your requirements become marginally more interesting, always use a flag variable instead if a range is necessary. What that means, of course, is that you can't use sed for problems like this since it doesn't support variables.

Anyway, here's a trivial GNU awk (for multi-char RS and RT) solution that doesn't directly use ranges at all:

```
$ cat file
Assuming the string: "<mask>123</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the

$ awk -v RS='</mask>' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/(.*<mask>).*/,"\\1***",1) RT}' file
Assuming the string: "<mask>***</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the
```

or if you need the number of `*`s to match the number of characters they're replacing:

```
$ cat file
Assuming  first string: "<mask>123</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the
Assuming second string: "<mask>1234567</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the

$ awk -v RS='</mask>' 'match($0,/(.*<mask>)(.*)/,a){ $0=a[1] gensub(/./,"*","g",a[2]) } {ORS=RT} 1' file
Assuming  first string: "<mask>***</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the
Assuming second string: "<mask>*******</mask><keep>123</keep>" ...I'd like the
```

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

why you got this output is completely correct. It is a trick of sed's range address of two regex.

What you gave sed is `/regex1/, /regex2/`,  sed will first try to find the line matches `address1`, which is `/regex1/`, the first line matched, fine. Then your `address2` is a regex too, so:

> and if  addr2 is a regexp, it will not be tested against the line
>   that addr1 matched.

This sentence is from sed's man page.

That is, sed starts checking your `/regex2/` from line 2. of course, no line matches the `/<\/mask>/`, so sed just did the substitution on whole file.

Check this example:

```
kent$  cat f
<mask>234</mask>
123
123
123
<mask>234</mask>
123
123
<keep>234</keep>

kent$  sed "/<mask>/,/<\/mask>/ s/[0-9]/*/g" f
<mask>***</mask>
***
***
***
<mask>***</mask>
123
123
<keep>234</keep>
```

Finally just a suggestion, don't process xml with regex (sed/awk/grep...).  Of course, you may just use the "xml" as an example.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks for the explanation.